# Firefox extension: unexpected property in contentscript permissions

Tags: json, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to load an extension, which was originally developed for Chrome, into Firefox. I'm aware that there are subtle differences, my idea was to fix the errors one by one.

The manifest can actually be loaded, an icon is added and the extension is listed as installed.
But during the loading, there are two warnings. One of them is:

```
Reading manifest: Error processing content_scripts.0.permissions: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me which property is unexpected. I opened the debug consoles, the message is identical, there is no additional information.

The `content_scripts` section from the manifest is this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": [
        "extra.css",
        "all.css",
        "bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "firebase.js",
        "jquery.min.js",
        "content.js",
        "popper.min.js",
        "bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://dlab.epfl.ch/*",
        "https://*.wikipedia.org/*"
      ],
      "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab"
      ]
    }],
```

The permissions look good to me. I checked against the Mozilla docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions), to avoid something like a spelling mistake. But `storage` and `activeTab` are allowed as permissions.

How can I find out what this unexpected property is ?

For reference, here is the full manifest: https://pastebin.com/dkaNmZHk

Comment: "permissions" should be in the main context, not inside "content_scripts".

Comment: Oh, somehow chrome swallows this without complaint.
Thanks for the quick response, if you turn this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @wOxxOm said, it is a simple mistake in the JSON layout:

`permissions` should be top-level and not within `content_scripts`.